# Multiple middleware Laravel

Tags: laravel, autenticación

Tengo dos tipos de guardia `Embajador y Experto` mi problema es que los dos pueden tener acceso a paginas similares. Mi problema es que en paginas donde son permitidos los dos tipos no me autoriza el acceso.
intente usar:

```
function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth:embajador,experto');
    }
```

Esto solo me deja ingresar con **embajador** pero no con experto y si lo pongo a la inversa es lo mismo, me deja con **experto** pero no con embajador.

Tambien intente usar:

```
function __construct(){
        $this->middleware(['auth:embajador','auth:experto']);
    }
```

y funciona solo si el primer auth se define. Esto lleva a una pagina inicial pero primero pasa por el middleware de autenticación, para evitar que otro usuario intente acceder.

Alguien sabe como puedo autorizar el acceso a estos dos tipos de usuario a una vista?